# how to iterate the required part of string in python

Tags: iteration

As a part of my project in python I  have to iterate the roll number which has 10 digits
our roll numbers be like:

```
188w1a0501,188w1a0502--------188w1a0599,188w1a05a1--188w1a05a9,188w1a05b1--188w1a05b9----
```

upto the last member .
getting these numbers one by one into a variable so that i can send them to my function.
How to do this?

Comment: What is the expected output based on this input?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of regular expression to get the roll numbers.

```
import re
data='188w1a0501, 188w1a0502--------188w1a0599, 188w1a05a1--188w1a05a9, 188w1a05b1--188w1a05b9----'
tokens = re.split(r",|-|\( | \)", data)

formatted = [token.strip() for token in tokens if len(token.strip())>0]
print(formatted)
```

Output would be

```
['188w1a0501', '188w1a0502', '188w1a0599', '188w1a05a1', '188w1a05a9', '188w1a05b1', '188w1a05b9']
```